# PHP Get Meta tags, URL's in Arrays = Not Working

Tags: php

I am trying to get the meta tags of the urls entered in the text area, what is wrong with this?

Also, how would I put the URL that the meta description came from with the description?

```
<form method="get">
<textarea name="TAData">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="PR" /> Show me the PR<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="KW Tag" /> Show me the KW tag<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Title Tag" /> Show me the Title tag<br />
</div>
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1stH1" /> Show me the 1st H1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="2ndH1" /> Show me the 2nd H1 tag<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SeedKW" /> Show me Seed KW's<br />
</div>

<div id="nofloat"></div>

<?php

//make the array 
$TAarray = explode("\n", strip_tags($_POST['TAData'])); 

var_dump($TAarray);

//loop through the array 
foreach ($TAarray as $line) { 


   $line = htmlspecialchars(trim($line)); 
}      

    foreach ($TAarray as $url) {

            // get the meta data for each url
            $tags = get_meta_tags($url);

unset($tags["content-type"]);
unset($tags["page-type"]);
unset($tags["page-topic"]);
unset($tags["audience"]);

                echo '<tr>';
                foreach ($tags['description'] as $meta)         
            {
                        echo '<td>' . $meta . '</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
        }
?>
```

Also, is there a way to only include the meta description?

Comment: You're checking `$_POST['TAData']` but your form method is `get`. Should be `post`.

Comment: Even if you are new to PHP, you probably know more than "not working". Please put some effort in your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I really didn't know anything else other then not working it was showing no errors...

Comment: Ok that worked michael but now I am getting another error I'll put in next post

Comment: @RickyDawn If it isn't showing errors, then be sure to do `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: The errors I am getting now are: '    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/play/public_html/testdir/metaex.php on line 300

    Warning: get_meta_tags() [function.get-meta-tags]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/play/public_html/testdir/metaex.php on line 51'

Comment: @RickyDawn: The error message contains the info what's wrong. The URL you pass to that function is invalid. Do proper error handling with your script and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) your form is declared as GET, but you are reading values from $_POST field.

2) if you want to extract just the "description" meta value, you don't need to do the iteration over tags, you can just use:

```
$description = $tags["description"]
```

Comment: The script is now working BUT only if I put one URL in the text area as soon as I go onto the second line it gives me the errors: **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** and **[function.get-meta-tags]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**

Comment: `foreach ($TAarray as $key => &$line) { $line = trim($line); }`