# PHP array only using the first line of text area for 'Get Meta Tags' Function

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP so please bear with me :)

What I am trying to do if place URL's into a text area, then pull in the meta data for each.

I have made the script, but when I place more then one URL into the text area it only returns data for the last URL entered, I thought maybe you guys can help me :)

```
<form method="POST">
<textarea name="TAData">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="PR" /> Show me the PR<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="KW Tag" /> Show me the KW tag<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Title Tag" /> Show me the Title tag<br />
</div>
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1stH1" /> Show me the 1st H1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="2ndH1" /> Show me the 2nd H1 tag<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SeedKW" /> Show me Seed KW's<br />
</div>

<div id="nofloat"></div>

<?php

//make the array 
$TAarray = explode("\n", strip_tags($_POST['TAData'])); 

foreach ($TAarray as $key => &$line) { $line = trim($line); }
            // get the meta data for each url
            $tags = get_meta_tags($line);

unset($tags["content-type"]);
unset($tags["page-type"]);
unset($tags["page-topic"]);
unset($tags["audience"]);
unset($tags["content-language"]);       

            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($tags as $meta)        
            {
                    echo '<td>' . $meta . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';

?>
```

Comment: Somewhat related to: [PHP Get Meta tags, URL's in Arrays = Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10092500/367456) - How is this question different to your previous one?

Comment: Because my previous problem no longer exists (the problem has changed) should I have kept it in the last question? I'm sorry!

Comment: No, you can ask multiple question, I was curious because your related (by topic) has no accepted answer so far. I suggest you start with writing yourself functions to do separate work so it's more easy to maintain and test.

Comment: You'll likely get more sensible answers if you trim down your question to just the relevant facts and code needed to reproduce the problem. You also seem rather confused about what a meta tag is (it's an element embedded in HTML, not HTTP) and how html works (form elements need to be enclosed in form tags to be included in a response)

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I'll try and stick to the errors next time, sorry I am new here.

Comment: Also the checkboxes are not supposed to be working yet, I was just getting the layout sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closing } after where you use trim on the line means that the foreach ends and only the last line is available after the loop for the other operations. Just move that bracket to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `foreach` with references, it's good practice to remove that reference after the loop:

```
foreach ($TAarray as $key => &$line)
{
    $line = trim($line); 
}
unset($line); # remove the reference for safety reasons
```

But as you don't iterate over `$TAarray` after that code, the code is superfluous anyway. Don't write superfluous code. I suggest the following:

```
//make the array 
$TAarray = explode("\n", strip_tags($_POST['TAData'])); 
$TAarray = array_map('trim', $TAarray);
```

And I suggest you put that into a function of it's own:

```
/**
 * @param string $html
 * @return string[] lines
 */
function getTrimmedTextLinesArrayFromHTMLBlock($html)
{
    $text = strip_tags($html);
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    $trimmed = array_map('trim', $lines);
    return $trimmed;
}
```

You can then use it wherever you see fit. You can also test this function independently with different input:

```
$lines = getTrimmedTextLinesArrayFromHTMLBlock($_POST['TAData']));
$blacklist= array("content-type", "page-type", "page-topic", 
                "audience", "content-language");
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    if (! $tags = get_meta_tags($line)) continue;
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($tags as $key => $meta)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $blacklist)) continue;
        echo '<td>' . $meta . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I hope this is helpful.